# GWT CAS Tomcat deploy fails

Tags: gwt, tomcat, cas

I upgraded my GWT project with CAS. When I test it in dev mode, it works fine. Now I wanted to deploy my project to tomcat. When I'm running it, I can reach the CAS server. But when the CAS server directs me back to my webapp, I'm getting this error.

> > HTTP Status 500 - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> >     find valid certification path to requested target
>
> type Exception report
>
> message javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:295)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:132)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>     sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1338)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:281)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:132)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)
>
> root cause
>
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>     sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
>     sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:281)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:132)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)
>
> root cause
>
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
>     java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
>     sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
>     sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
>     sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
>     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
>     sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
>     sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:281)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:132)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
>     org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.37 logs. Apache Tomcat/7.0.37

Can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming  you enabled `https=true` in `deployDescriptor.xml`. Inorder to make CAS work with `HTTPS`  you have to create one [keystore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) file

[Creating a Keystore File](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19636-01/819-1655/fapsf/index.html)

Comment: What do u mean by deployDescriptor.xml?

Comment: i mean deployConfigContext.xml..where you pasted the keystore file on tomcat??

Comment: into the main folder. this is my server.xml entry.

Comment: <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="8443" keystoreFile=".keystore" keystorePass="password"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />

Comment: do u mean the deployConfigContext.xml of my cas? where do i have to set https=true?

Comment: You set in the right way only ...and my path is keystoreFile="E://apache-tomcat-6.0.36//keystore"

Comment: i think this isnt the point. cause as i said: I CAN reach the server via https. and i reach my cas server. im just getting that exception, when the cas server leads me back to my webapp.